# C# Linq - how to select top 5 rows from a List<string> splitting on the first value

Tags: c#, linq, select

I probably worded this the wrong way, but I have a simple List that based on a split I want the greatest values from the first column.

Here is the code

```
   List<string> myString = new List<string>();
        myString.Add("100.02|apples|pears");
        myString.Add("22.02|apples|pears");
        myString.Add("99.02|apples|pears");
        myString.Add("88.02|apples|pears");
        myString.Add("77.02|apples|pears");
        myString.Add("66.02|apples|pears");
```

I'm basically splitting on `|` and then converting the first column to decimal.  I want to get the greatest 5 rows to this would exclude 22.02.  I've tried sorting and ordering but they dont work because the strings are differnt lengths.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This will work:

```
List<string> myString = new List<string>();
myString.Add("100.02|apples|pears");
myString.Add("22.02|apples|pears");
myString.Add("99.02|apples|pears");
myString.Add("88.02|apples|pears");
myString.Add("77.02|apples|pears");
myString.Add("66.02|apples|pears");

var res = myString.Select(s => new
{
    num = decimal.Parse(s.Split('|')[0]),
    str = s
}).OrderByDescending(g => g.num).Take(5).Select(s => s.str);
res.Dump();
```

No error checking whatsoever, but it gives you the result:

> 100.02|apples|pears
>   99.02|apples|pears
>   88.02|apples|pears
>   77.02|apples|pears
>   66.02|apples|pears

Comment: Rob - how do you iterate it?  res.ToArray()?

Comment: @JoshuaLong You can do `foreach(var something in res) { ... }`. But yes, ToArray, ToList(), etc, will all immediately evaluate the enumerable

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Select` to do operations on each element in your list.

like

```
var result = myString.Select(s => s + "-helloworld").ToArray();
```

then `result[0]` will equal `"100.02|apples|pears-helloworld"`

If you use `s.Split('|')`, then you get an string[] (array of strings) for each element.  You can use `.First()` to take the first element.

Joining it all together,

```
var result = myString.Select(s => s.Split('|').First())
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out how to parse a string to a decimal.